# A software to help learning abstract algebra

Tags: math, symbolic-algebra

What kind of programs there are for a math student to solve problems and prove theorems related to abstract algebra?

Answer (score 1):

[SageMath](https://www.sagemath.org/) is an open-source mathematics software system that integrates various mathematical software packages. It includes functionality for algebraic computations, group theory, ring theory, and other topics in abstract algebra.

[Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/) is another interactive theorem prover that supports higher-order logic. It provides a framework for constructing formal proofs and conducting mathematical reasoning. It is used in formal verification and can be utilized to prove theorems related to abstract algebra.